# Material UI Menu not closing on mouse right click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a menu which I is opening on mouse click of a tab

```
  ...
  <Tab 
      label={page.title}
      title={page.description}
      onMouseDown={this.pageMenuOpen}
  />
  ...

  <Menu
      id="simple-menu"
      anchorReference="anchorPosition"
      anchorPosition={{top: this.state.pageMenu.y, left: this.state.pageMenu.x}}
      open={this.state.pageMenu.open}
      onClose={this.pageMenuClose}
   >
```

This works as expected, the pageMenuOpen function is changing the state of the pageMenu.open to true and the menu opens, also the pageMenuClose is changing it to false and that works as well.
The Menu onClose function runs on ESC and on mouse left clicking away from the menu.

Is there an option to make it run the function on right clicking away as well? Or override when onClose shall be run? I have noticed the same is happening on the Dialog as well.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't override onClose trigger event, but you can get a look at the other events in here https://material-ui.com/api/menu/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
<Menu
  onContextMenu={(e) => {
    // prevent the default browser context menu
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.classList.contains('MuiBackdrop-root')) {
      // close here
    }
}}
>
```